# How to move project under source-control from one folder to another?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

is there a way to move a project that is under source control to another folder? example, i want to move all projects under 'Accounting' to 'Archives'. I don't seem to get an option to do so, other than adding new files, uploading new files, etc.

[image: options i get when i right-click on the folder]

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: @DanielMann i am using Azure DevOps TFS. This is just the web facing application

Comment: That didn't answer my question. There are two methods of version control available: Git, or TFVC. "Azure DevOps TFS" isn't an option.

Comment: The correct term here is TFVC. TFS is the product that hosts the version control system, which can be TFVC or Git. From the image OP posted it is crystal clear that this is about TFVC.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move files or folders through the TFS interface. You can move projects only from within Visual Studio or through the command line. To do it through Visual Studio (I'm using VS2022 as a reference):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. On the home screen, click 'Continue without code'
3. Go to the 'Team Explorer' tab or search for that tab using Ctrl + Q and typing 'Team Explorer'
4. Open 'Source Control Explorer' from that menu, or search for that menu using Ctrl + Q and typing 'Source Control Explorer' and observe the list of folders.
5. To move anything in here, right-click it and select Move, then go through the dialog.
6. Check in the changes you made when you moved the folders.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no such option could directly move folder to another folder in Azure DevOps Repo UI page.

For a workaround, you could use git command or Visual Studio source control explorer to achieve this.

Here is the git command sample:

```
git clone cloneurl

change the folder path on local env     

git add .
  
git commit –m “Change folder path”

git push
```

Comment: OP was talking about TFVC, not Git